# Use local version of node.js package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm digging into a node package that uses a CLI, and am trying to extend it by adding some functionality. I've cloned the repo from github, but I've also installed it via npm.

How can I use my local version, instead of the one that's been installed via npm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install a package using npm, it just puts it into the node_modules folder in the folder where you ran it (or if you pass -g, into a global node_modules folder).

require() uses a particular search order to find modules.  To get a specific version of a module to load you can take two paths:

1. Specify a relative path to the module: require("./path/to/myfork/of/module")
2. Delete the version of the module installed by npm into mode_modules and put your fork of it in there
3. Make sure that your fork of that module is in a "closer" node_modules folder.  Node searches the node_modules in same folder as the file calling require() and then works its way up the folder hierarchy to find a module.

For more information, take a look at http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/modules.html